# Printing large excel file to pdf taking too long (more than 15 minutes)

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf, printing

I have a fairly large excel file with about 70 tabs and a lot of macros.

I'm trying to print the file to .pdf but it takes nearly 15 min to complete. I've tried using the Adobe print to pdf as well as the Microsoft print to pdf as well. I've also tried File - Save as Adobe pdf and that also takes a really long time.

Is there any work around for this?

Thanks so much

Comment: Why is this a problem? Acquiring more patience is probably the best solution

Answer (score 1):

Consider automating printing each worksheet as its own .pdf and using Acrobat Pro to assemble.  As a bonus, that may help you identify a pattern of which worksheets if any are difficult.

Answer (score 0):

It takes a long time for a large excel file to print as pdf, not to mention that you still have 70 macros. Replacing a better device may increase speed.